# Не работает адрес сайта

Tags: php

Я развернул сайт по [адресу](http://shihzamanapp.com) но зайти на него не получается, попасть можно на сайт только если в строке запроса поставлю два слеша вот так `shihzamanapp.com//`.
С чем это может быть связанно?

Comment: почем у название индекс файла index.html_ ?

Comment: попробуй *sitename*/index.php

Comment: 1. `index.html_`, 2. Настройте открытие сайта т.е. **Routing**

Comment: @doox911 я пробовал настроить индекс на путь shohzamanapp.com. Появляется ошибка 404

Comment: Конфиги? B Я так понял надо настраивать на папку `web`. `index.html` подправьте

Comment: что за интересный формат страницы? '.html_"